# SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog does not work for site pages or external link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

The code below keeps giving an error

> "Sorry, something went wrong -- an unexpected error has occurred."

I tried the same code to open an Excel workbook from another library and it worked.

The path being returned by SecCalUrl is the correct path to the calendar. I also found out it doesn't like & in the name, that's way "Cost & Billing" is separated.

```
function getFileName(mySection){

var webAbsUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
switch (mySection){

    case 'Cost & Billing':
        var SecCalUrl = webAbsUrl + "/SitePages/Calendar_Div_Brc_Sec.aspx";
        var options = {url: SecCalUrl, width: 800, height:950, title: "Calendar"};
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
        break;

    default:

        var requestUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Organization')/Items?$filter=Section eq '" + mySection + "'&$select=SecAcron, DivAcron, BrcAcron";
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.results.length > 0) {
                    var mySecAcron = data.d.results[0].SecAcron;
                    var myBrcAcron = data.d.results[0].BrcAcron;
                    var myDivAcron = data.d.results[0].DivAcron;
                    var SecCalUrl = webAbsUrl + "/SitePages/Calendar_" + myDivAcron + "_" + myBrcAcron + "_" + mySecAcron+ ".aspx?isDlg=1";
                    var options = {url: SecCalUrl, width: 800, height:950, title: "Calendar"};
                    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

                }
            },
            error: function (data) { alert("Failed to load your profile."); }
        });
}   

}
```

Edit 12/4: I did some testing with below code.  It will open any URL to any list or files -- but it wouldn't open any site page URL or any external site (i.e. google).

```
function openDialog() {

var options = {
    url: "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName",  
    //above opens list but wouldnt open https://xxx.sharepoint.com/SitePages/home.aspx or http://www.google.com
    title: "Calendar",
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    width: 900,
    height: 800 
};

SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my testing, wiki page and Modern page are not supported in modal dialog currently.

One thread for your reference.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother-mso_o365b/using-isdlg-with-pages/286f324c-3054-4d7c-8ae9-d928fd2e1b17

Comment: Thanks. I just left the link to open in new or current tab.